# Cannot retrieve class value with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Building a basic webscraper and I cannot retrieve the class value that contains a product's price. The class name for all of the prices listed on the google search is `qptdjc`.

Here is the HTML tag for the price
`<div class="qptdjc">$179.99</div>`

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver as wb
import pandas as pd
import time

browser = wb.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/ethan/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1)/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=nnZ6X8SDO4WE9PwPj5KC4AQ&q=144hz+monitor&oq=144hz+monitor&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQsQMyBQgAELEDMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6DggAEOoCELQCEJoBEOUCOgsILhDHARCvARCTAjoFCC4QsQM6CAguEMcBEK8BOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6CAguELEDEIMBOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCvAVDyDligHmDsH2gBcAB4AIABiwGIAZMHkgEEMTIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQY&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjEyoykppzsAhUFAp0JHQ-JAEwQ4dUDCAk&uact=5')

productInfoList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('qptdjc')
prices = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="qptdjc"]')

prices_list = []
for p in range(len(prices)):
    prices_list.append(prices[p].text)

print(len(productInfoList))
print(*prices_list, sep = ", ")
print(*prices, sep = ", ")
```

Comment: Have a small question do you want the previous price or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I waited for all the elements to appear. Grabbed all of them, looped and got their inner HTML.

```
productInfoList=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.r4awE > span")))
prices=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.qptdjc")))

prices_list = []
for price in prices:
    prices_list.append(price.get_attribute('innerHTML').split('<')[0].strip())
pprint(prices_list)
print(len(productInfoList))
```

Outputs

```
['$229.99',
 '$187.52',
 '$249.99']
3
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from pprint import pprint
```

Comment: thank you, why do you use `by.CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `by.XPATH`? All of the tutorials I have been using use the latter.

Comment: CSS_SELECTOR tends to be faster than xpath.